# Software that simulates a LAN admin

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, lan

You know you recommend a software that simulates a LAN, to use as a virtual test environment before you apply the settings on physical machines? Should I install it on Windows 7.

Comment: do you need GUI?

Comment: If possibly, yes...

Comment: Thank you. There is nothing equivalent for Windows? Only for Linux?

Comment: Can you give a larger overview of what you are trying to test out, do you want to test a application on a network or are you testing network topology itself?

Comment: Network topology itself!

Answer (score 0):

This is a common use of Virtual Machine software. VMWare's [VMWare Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) is free for non commercial uses. You can set up several virtual machines and they can be on their own private network that only they share.

Comment: Scott, thanks for the reply, but I would an environment for learning, already use virtualization software, but they are not in my case ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use NS on Linux. [NS is a network simulation tool](http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/).

NS is a discrete event simulator targeted at networking research. Ns provides substantial support for simulation of TCP, routing, and multicast protocols over wired and wireless (local and satellite) networks.

By default it's for Linux, but now a Windows version came out!